# Generalized Eigen Values and Vectors in Eigen Library

Tags: linear-algebra, eigen, eigenvector

How do I find **generalized Eigen Values, Vectors** using **Eigen3** library?

In octave, matlab, the eigen value function is of the form: `[V, lambda] = eig (A, B)`.

I could only find [this](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1GeneralizedSelfAdjointEigenSolver.html) **Class** in **Eigen3 lib** but was not helpful in validating the results from above matlab/octave code.

Comment: I have 2 square matrices **A,B**. I want to make use of "Generalized Eigen Solving" mechanism which is of the form **Ax = λBx**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use the [`EigenSolver`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1EigenSolver.html) class which is located in the `Eigen/Eigenvalues` header. Either use the `EigenSolver` constructor that takes a matrix parameter or of or call the `compute` method with a matrix and it will solve for that matrix's eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Then you can use the `eigenvalues()` and `eigenvectors()` methods to retrieve the eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Comment: I have 2 matrices A and B with which I want to calculate Eigen Values, Eigen Vectors. The function that you pointed to requires only 1 matrix. How do I use it in this case? I'm looking for something like in matlab where it can solve generalized eigenvalue problem Ax = λBx.

Answer (score 0):

This question is old. Anyway, if someone here is looking for it, they should consider the GeneralizedEigenSolver (http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1GeneralizedEigenSolver.html) that is available in the Eigen library. Although, at this time, as far as I know, it is not completely ready.